# Unipotent Groups and Torsors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I've been doing some reading in some arithmetic geometry, and there's a subtle point that is confusing me slightly: say $U$ is some unipotent affine group scheme over a field $L$, and $T$ is some right $U$-torsor. Then the claim is that $T$ contains a global point over $L$ i.e. $T(L) \neq \emptyset$.

I'm really not that sure on where to go with this, and how to demonstrate existence of these global points? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the base field $L$ is perfect and $U$ is reduced, then the unipotent group is split and thus it contains $\mathbb{G}_a$. Then consider the orbit of this subgroup. This orbit is a locally closed subvariety and thus contains a rational point. These. results are there in section 15 of borel's book on Linear Algebraic Groups.

Comment: To clarify that, perhaps because I'm still a little slow on this: $U$ will be an extension of some subgroup $U'$ by $\mathbb{G}_a$, and the fact that $U$ is reduced over $L$ implies we get a splitting exhibiting $\mathbb{G}_a$ as a subgroup. So then if we look at the orbit of $\mathbb{G}_a$ we get a locally closed subvariety $T'$ which will be isomorphic to $U'$. Then as we know that $U'(L)$ should contain the identity element and so $T'(L) \neq \emptyset$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The definition of split unipotent groups implies by definition that it has a copy of $\mathbb{G_a}$ inside it. Also for the latter part of the argument i am using a proposition of Borel which says that if $\mathbb{G_a}$ acts transitvely on a variety X, then X has a point in the base field. This proposition is in the first 3-4 pages of section 15.

Comment: Ah right, I've got it - couldn't locate the proposition as I was looking in the wrong place! Thanks

Comment: Great! Maybe i should have been more precise.